# Retrieving specific data based on ID from SQLite in ANDROID

Tags: android, database, sqlite, search

I wrote a code in which i can retrieve the data from the database but when i run it and try to search something. The application crashes as soon as i press Submit

```
public class search extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button SearchButton;
    EditText SearchText;
    TextView SearchResult;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String builder;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);
        SearchButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.searchbutton);
        SearchText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Searchtext);
        SearchResult=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.SearchCourse);
        db=this.openOrCreateDatabase("Courses", Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);

        SearchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int GetID = Integer.valueOf(SearchText.getText().toString());
                Cursor TuplePointer = db.rawQuery("Select from Course where ID="+GetID+"",null);

                TuplePointer.moveToFirst();
                String Course = TuplePointer.getString(TuplePointer.getColumnIndex("Course"));
                SearchResult.setText(Course);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line

```
Cursor TuplePointer = db.rawQuery("Select from Course where ID=" + GetID + "", null);
```

with

```
Cursor TuplePointer = db.rawQuery("Select Course from Course where ID=" + GetID + "", null);
```

Where `Course` is your column name

Answer (score 0):

**Please Try this**

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String GetID = SearchText.getText().toString();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Course WHERE ID = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(GetID)}, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String Course = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Course"));
            SearchResult.setText(Course);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Comment: How can i display in textview then?

Comment: cursor.moveToFirst();
                String Course = TuplePointer.getString(TuplePointer.getColumnIndex("Course"));
                SearchResult.setText(Course);

Comment: still crashes :(

Comment: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: your database any record insert or not.

Comment: Yes i can retrieve data from viewall function and it shows me 4 records

Comment: db=this.openOrCreateDatabase("Courses", Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null); db.getWritableDatabase();

Comment: Still unable to use it

Answer (score 0):

Write your code within try catch first. Afterthat try to catch exact exception. you will be clear what are you doing wrong.

```
 String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS + " Where " + KEY_APP_BOOKINGID + " = " + id;

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You everyone I figured out what i was doing wrong on the get Column index i targeted course but what i didnt realize is that there was no such field as course :)

Answer (score -1):

> Keep practice like below code you will debug proper

```
public void getFirstName(String id) {
    String sql = "select  first_name from basic_info WHERE contact_id="+ id;
    Cursor c = fetchData(sql);
    if (c != null) {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {

            String FirstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("first_name"));
            Log.e("Result =>",FirstName);
        }
        c.close();
    }
    return data; 
}

public Cursor fetchData(String sql) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    return db.rawQuery(sql, null);
}
```